# Beanshell script for iterating over csv file

Tags: beanshell

I have a post request in the below format
{
"action": "CN",
"contract": "138484833",
"company": "B",
"job_number": 1234564,
"timestamp": 2020121710470000
}

I need to test the above scenario for 100 users, I tried with beanshell script below is the code

```
enter code here
try{

    StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();

    requestBody.append("{\"action\":\"CN\",\"company\":\"B\",\"timestamp\":\"2020121710470000\",\"contract\":\"c\",\"jobnumber\":\"j\"");

    log.info("hi");

    log.info(vars.get("requestBody"));

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\jkuma408SA2\\Documents\\postfile.csv")));

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] data = line.split(",");

        requestBody.replace(71,74,data[1]);

        requestBody.replace(92,94,data[2]);
           
        requestBody.append("\"").append(line).append("\"").append(",");
    }
    reader.close();

    print(requestBody);
    
    
    requestBody.append("}");

   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);

   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",requestBody.toString(),"");
}
   catch(Exception e) {

      log.info("hi there");
    }
```

I am getting "null" value in my requestBody variable, can anyone please help me with this code.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

`requestBody` isn't saved as JMeter variable so `log.info(vars.get("requestBody"));` not working

Change to logging local variable

```
log.info(requestBody);
```